# Process XML through ajax in Spring 3.0

Tags: spring, jquery, spring-mvc

How can POST XML (approximately 30000 lines) as data , in jQuery in Spring 3.0 .

Comment: Get the HTTP response object, get it's OutputStream, and start writing.

Comment: that depends do you want to send it as string or file?